# How to find a unique HTML element?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking at a URL with a bunch of tags named 'tspan'. Is it possible that this is hidden, or somehow not exposed?

How can I grab the 'extract' plus the 'source_load' and all other tspan elements, load everything into a list, and dump the list to a file on my desktop?  Here is the code that I'm testing.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import webbrowser
import requests


REQUEST_URL = 'https://corp-intranet.com/admin/'
response = requests.get(REQUEST_URL, auth=('em_email', 'pswd'))
xml_data = response.text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')


url_list = ['https://corp-intranet.com/admin/ad_history']

for link in url_list:
    File = webbrowser.open(link)
    File = requests.get(link)
    data = File.text
    soup = bs(data, "lxml") 
    all_text = []
    for link in soup.findAll('tspan'):
        all_text.append(link.get('tspan'))
        print(all_text)

with open('C:/Users/ryans/OneDrive/Desktop/test.txt', 'wb') as outfile:
    for f in all_text:
        with open(f, '\n') as infile:
            outfile.write(f.encode('utf-8'))
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Comment: Is the element present in the original HTTP payload, or is it added after the page loads?

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I think that your basic approach is too.. basic

*Base Assumption*

Although you are downloading html files from remote servers, your base operation still relies on **text manipulation**. No doubt - you can do it by yourself. On the other hand - why? My base assumption is that you can reduce your work load by using a third-party library

*Use Html **scraper***

Because HTML is so wildly use, almost every platform / programming language has at least one good library that helps you manipulate HTML content (most likely while using `XPath`). **For instance:** C# programmers will probably use [Agility-Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) for that purpose

*Suggested Solution*

Use [lxml](https://lxml.de/) - it does exactly what you need. [Here](https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/scrape/) is a great post that explain and demonstrate how to get started with it. In short:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
buyers = tree.xpath('//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()')
```

This should cover your requirements

Comment: Hello ymz.  I just tried your code and I'm seeing this:
buyers = tree.xpath('//div[@title="tspan"]/text()')
In [75]: buyers
Out[75]: []

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `get_text()` method to get the text of a tag. `tag.get(...)` is used to get something that is within the tag. Try `all_text.append(link.get_text())`

Also, if the content you need is loaded dynamically and don't appear in the original page source, you won't see it with requests. You can use selenium to overcome this ([quick start guide here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)).

Comment: Thanks Shay.  Maybe I do need Selenium for this, but I don't think so.  I started with that, and I couldn't get the 'tspan' element, so I switched to a more basic (non-Selenium) solution.

Comment: Also, I tried the following:
for link in url_list:
   all_text.append(link.get_text())

That throws the following error:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try bs.get_text(link). Tell me if it worked so I can edit my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, no:
for link in url_list:
    bs.get_text(link)

Gives:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_all_strings'

Comment: I'm not sure why the soup.findAll doesn't return anything.  I've used that in the past and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Perhaps because you use the old syntax. Now it's bs.find_all(). Does this make a difference?

Comment: If not, what do you get when printing soup.findAll('tspan')?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185369/discussion-between-shay-w-and-ryguy72).